# Suppress module details when building Haskell project with Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've recently switched from building my project with Stack to building it with Cabal. For each module Stack used to output something similar to the following:

```
[54 of 54] Compiling Vehicle
```

but Cabal now outputs the much harder to read:

```
[54 of 54] Compiling Vehicle          ( src/hs/Vehicle.hs, /home/matthew/Code/AISEC/vehicle/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.0.1/vehicle-0.1.0.1/build/Vehicle.o, /home/matthew/Code/AISEC/vehicle/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.0.1/vehicle-0.1.0.1/build/Vehicle.dyn_o )
```

Is it possible to suppress the extra output in Cabal? I've trawled through `cabal build --help` but I can't any relevant options.